# Understanding scoping rules of python - using foo.var , self.var and var

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code

```
class foo:
  str = "Hello World"
  def test(self):
    print(str)

a = foo()
a.test()
```

I wanted to know if `print(str)` can actually access the str variable ? If so why does the output only display

```
<type 'str'>
```

Now I have been reading about python for a little while but I am confused with this situation. I understand that if I did something like the following

```
self.str
```

python would initially look in the instance for a variable called `str` and if the variables is not found then it would look for class variables otherwise if I wanted to access the class variable directly I would use

```
foo.str
```

so my question is which variable is being accessed with `print(str)`
is `foo.str` same as using `str` ?

Comment: No, `str` is a global in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused because you picked the wrong variable name. `str` is the built-in string type. You have to use `self.` prefix within your class methods and instance prefix outside them.

```
class foo:      
  s = "Hello World"
  def test(self):
    print(s)   # s not found
    print(self.s)  # OK!
```

Note that you defined a *class* variable, shared between instances of the same class (with wierd effects sometimes). Reserve that usage to constants.

To define an *instance* variable do:

```
class foo:    
  def __init__(self):  
      self.s = "Hello World"
```

So you can change `s` on instance `A` without risking to change it on instance `B` (well it's different for immutables like strings or ints, but you don't want to do that anyway)

Comment: "shared between instances of the same class" is perhaps less confusing

Comment: less confusing or even _not wrong_ :) thanks. Fixed (you _knew_ I didn't mean that :))

Comment: I was convinced, hence the humble comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Without self:**

foo.str is a class variable, and will be shared across all instances of foo, unless specifically overridden within an instance.

**With self:**

foo.str is an instance variable, and each instance of foo has its own version of it.

**Note:**

Notice that it's not good practice to call your variable str as it's a keyword in python